# jquery javascript question

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

var val = $("#desc").val();   // input box
    var val2 = $("#type").val();  // select box
    if((val=='') || (val2 == ''))
         {
         alert("err");
         }
    else { // codes }

when i select dropdown and not type anything on inputbox, the alert err still comes out?

how to make it when dropdown is selected, it goes to else clause?

Comment: You need to show us how you're capturing the event...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var val = $("#desc").val();   // input box
var val2 = $("#type").val();  // select box
if((val=='') && (val2 == ''))
     {
     alert("err");
     }
else { // codes }
```

Comment: Huh? How do you know he wants `&&` instead of `||`? I'm not seeing that implied in the question anywhere.

Comment: Such a simple fix I almost missed it the first time I read your solution. Well done.

Comment: @T.J. : "*when i select dropdown and not type anything on inputbox, the alert err still comes out?*".
That suggests that when he selects a value in the dropdown and leaves the input empty, he does not want the error to show.
I think this is a great pick-up by Salil.